# sort() doesn't work with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, sorting

i am trying to get a couple of values; that couple is formed by `i` and `j` ; the addition between them could be `N` or `N+1` . i want a list with the numbers that satisfy the condition. 
for example if N=3 then i need an output like this:

```
>>> [ [1,2], [2,2]  ]
```

my code so far is:

```
N = 3
answer = []
answer = [(i,j) for i in range (1,N) for j in range(1,N) if [i,j].sort() not in answer and i+j == N or i+j == N+1 ]
print(answer)
```

but when i run this, i receive this output:

```
>>> [ [1,2] , [2,1], [2,2] ]
```

where the nested list (couple) [2,1] is a  repetead element. why sort is not working in this code?

Comment: Just say no to depending on side-effects.

Comment: i do not understand @CharlesDuffy , what are you meaning with "say no depending on side-effects "; if you could give some example in code it will be helpfull.

Comment: `list.sort()` sorts your list in-place *as a side effect* (in the functional-programming sense of the term), as opposed to returning a sorted list.

Comment: @Alexis `[1, 3]` also satisfies that condition. No? (For N=3, N+1=4 and 1+3=4)

Comment: @ettanany in this particular case i need numbers below N. i mean if N = 5 valid pairs are : [1,4],[2,3],[3,3]... but no one have to be equal or greater than 5.

Comment: @Alexis How is [3,3] below 5 for N=5?

Comment: For N=3, what's the difference between [2, 2] and [1, 3]? Why [2, 2] should be taken but not [1, 3]?

Comment: this portion of code is just part of something more bigger.  i use the couples (the members of these couples are totally limited to be lesser than N). The restriction is just in this case; of course in another case it may be valid to have a member of a pair is greater or equal to N. but in this particular case i need only numbers below to N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inplace `.sort()` method is one problem, but the `answer` is empty list, and it's not updated in the list comprehension until it finishes, so probably you also have to use a regular for loop and if you don't want to check if elements are already in `answer`, use a set:

```
answer = set()
values = set([N, N+1])
for i in range(1,N):
    for j in range(1,N):
        if i + j in values:
            answer.add(tuple(sorted((i, j))))

answer
# {(1, 2), (2, 2)}
```